# Getting the order status of the vehicles on order

Tags: sql, db2, db2-400

I am trying to determine the status of the vehicle on order -Whether it is stock or Sold , whether it is part of the BAM campaign or not and the sold or stock date based on the following set of rules

1. If the data column orderstatus has *SLD ,SLD or SOLD then the comment column is sold ; if the orderstatus column has STOCK or *STOCK or STK followed by date (like STK 05/13) or *STK followed by date then the comment column is stock
2. if the orderstatus column has * or BAM or any date (For ex: 5/13,05/17/2022) then the BAMYN column would be BAM
3. For the Soldorstockdate output column if the column orderstatus has a date then that date would be the soldorstock date otherwise the date in the column orddate would be the Soldorstockdate

Please find the DDL for the input and output tables...Can you please help me here..

```
Input table

create table ##input
(segment varchar(20),
mmodel varchar(40),
brand varchar(30),
orderstatus varchar(100),
orddate date)

    insert into ##input values
    ('maka','M12E4','Nimg','*SLD 05/11/2022','5/1/2022'),
    ('sika','KL6781','Cheung','37141 SLD BAM','5/5/2022'),
    ('kloi','NB1290','Vloti','1277489 STK#39298.32831','5/4/2022'),
    ('Ping','BN1289','gower','36888 SLD FLOREN ANGEL','5/6/2022'),
    ('Melow','VB1901','operw','1286664 051222','5/10/2022'),
    ('Bekow','XC901','mewar','*SLD 5/14/22 Heman','5/3/2022'),
    ('Nakin','JH121','korew','STOCK','5/16/2022'),
    ('Verura','CV123','thilla','1287002 LONGMINT','5/12/2022'),
    ('Chaluli','BN8901','dora','STOCK BAM 5/17/22','5/11/2022'),
    ('Kroger','XC123','iops','*STOCK BAM 5/23/22','5/8/2022'),
    ('beqow','VB123','pirar','3902120 STOCK','5/20/2022'),
    ('Viast','NM41W','kolpe','SOLD BRANDON BOX 36790','5/15/2022'),
    ('Chimmin','BN123','tyrow','STK 5/13','5/3/2022'),
    ('Bellow','Vio23','Callow','*STK 5/13/22','5/5/2022'),
    ('Nalla','Krowmin','Gilqa','37938 STOCK 5/18/22 PER SARA','5/18/2022')

Output table

create table ##output
(segment varchar (20),
mmodel varchar(40),
brand varchar(30),
orderstatus varchar(100),
orddate date,
comment varchar(40),
BAMYN varchar(10),
soldorstockdate date)

insert into ##output values
('maka','M12E4','Nimg','*SLD 05/11/2022','5/1/2022','Sold','BAM','5/11/2022'),
('sika','KL6781','Cheung','37141 SLD BAM','5/5/2022','Sold','BAM','5/5/2022'),
('kloi','NB1290','Vloti','1277489 STK#39298.32831','5/4/2022','','',''),
('Ping','BN1289','gower','36888 SLD FLOREN ANGEL','5/6/2022','Sold','','5/6/2022'),
('Melow','VB1901','operw','1286664 051222','5/10/2022','','',''),
('Bekow','XC901','mewar','*SLD 5/14/22 Heman','5/3/2022','Sold','BAM','5/14/2022'),
('Nakin','JH121','korew','STOCK','5/16/2022','Stock','','5/16/2022'),
('Verura','CV123','thilla','1287002 LONGMINT','5/12/2022','','',''),
('Chaluli','BN8901','dora','STOCK BAM 5/17/22','5/11/2022','Stock','BAM','5/17/2022'),
('Kroger','XC123','iops','*STOCK BAM 5/23/22','5/8/2022','Stock','BAM','5/23/2022'),
('beqow','VB123','pirar','3902120 STOCK','5/20/2022','Stock','','5/20/2022'),
('Viast','NM41W','kolpe','SOLD BRANDON BOX 36790','5/15/2022','Sold','','5/15/2022'),
('Chimmin','BN123','tyrow','STK 5/13/2022','5/3/2022','Stock','BAM','5/13/2022'),
('Bellow','Vio23','Callow','*STK 5/13/22','5/5/2022','Stock','BAM','5/13/2022'),
('Nalla','Krowmin','Gilqa','37938 STOCK 5/18/22 PER SARA','5/18/2022','Stock','BAM','5/18/2022')
```

Input table

| Segment | mmodel | brand | orderstatus | orddate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| maka | M12E4 | Nimg | *SLD 05/11/2022 | 5/1/2022 |
| sika | KL6781 | Cheung | 37141 SLD BAM | 5/5/2022 |
| kloi | NB1290 | Vloti | 1277489 STK#39298.32831 | 5/4/2022 |
| Ping | BN1289 | gower | 36888 SLD FLOREN ANGEL | 5/6/2022 |
| Melow | VB1901 | operw | 1286664 051222 | 5/10/2022 |
| Bekow | XC901 | mewar | *SLD 5/14/22 Heman | 5/3/2022 |
| Nakin | JH121 | korew | STOCK | 5/16/2022 |
| Verura | CV123 | thilla | 1287002 LONGMINT | 5/12/2022 |
| Chaluli | BN8901 | dora | STOCK BAM 5/17/22 | 5/11/2022 |
| Kroger | XC123 | iops | *STOCK BAM 5/23/22 | 5/8/2022 |
| beqow | VB123 | pirar | 3902120 STOCK | 5/20/2022 |
| Viast | NM41W | kolpe | SOLD BRANDON BOX 36790 | 5/15/2022 |
| Chimmin | BN123 | tyrow | STK 5/13 | 5/3/2022 |
| Bellow | Vio23 | Callow | *STK 5/13/22 | 5/5/2022 |
| Nalla | Krowmin | Gilqa | 37938 STOCK 5/18/22 PER SARA | 5/18/2022 |

Output table

| Segment | mmodel | brand | orderstatus | orddate | comment | BAM-Yes or no | Soldorstockdate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| maka | M12E4 | Nimg | *SLD 05/11/2022 | 5/1/2022 | Sold | BAM | 5/11/2022 |
| sika | KL6781 | Cheung | 37141 SLD BAM | 5/5/2022 | Sold | BAM | 5/5/2022 |
| kloi | NB1290 | Vloti | 1277489 STK#39298.32831 | 5/4/2022 |  |  |  |
| Ping | BN1289 | gower | 36888 SLD FLOREN ANGEL | 5/6/2022 | Sold |  | 5/6/2022 |
| Melow | VB1901 | operw | 1286664 051222 | 5/10/2022 |  |  |  |
| Bekow | XC901 | mewar | *SLD 5/14/22 Heman | 5/3/2022 | Sold | BAM | 5/14/2022 |
| Nakin | JH121 | korew | STOCK | 5/16/2022 | Stock |  | 5/16/2022 |
| Verura | CV123 | thilla | 1287002 LONGMINT | 5/12/2022 |  |  |  |
| Chaluli | BN8901 | dora | STOCK BAM 5/17/22 | 5/11/2022 | Stock | BAM | 5/17/2022 |
| Kroger | XC123 | iops | *STOCK BAM 5/23/22 | 5/8/2022 | Stock | BAM | 5/23/2022 |
| beqow | VB123 | pirar | 3902120 STOCK | 5/20/2022 | Stock |  | 5/20/2022 |
| Viast | NM41W | kolpe | SOLD BRANDON BOX 36790 | 5/15/2022 | Sold |  | 5/15/2022 |
| Chimmin | BN123 | tyrow | STK 5/13/2022 | 5/3/2022 | Stock | BAM | 5/13/2022 |
| Bellow | Vio23 | Callow | *STK 5/13/22 | 5/5/2022 | Stock | BAM | 5/13/2022 |
| Nalla | Krowmin | Gilqa | 37938 STOCK 5/18/22 PER SARA | 5/18/2022 | Stock | BAM | 5/18/2022 |

I am trying to find out how to extract the Dates in the orderstatus column and to choose only values that have STK followed by date as stock in comment

Also looking for dates in the orderstatus column that are only of the format mm/dd/yy or mm/dd/yyyy or mm/dd

**UPDATE**

Query tried in DB2

```
    SELECT a.*, CASE WHEN REGEXP_COUNT(PUR_ORD,'SLD')>0 THEN 'Sold' 
      WHEN REGEXP_COUNT ('%STOCK%',PUR_ORD)>0 OR REGEXP_COUNT ('STK[0-9]/[0-9]',PUR_ORD)>0 THEN 'Stock' ELSE'' END AS comment 
             ,CASE WHEN REGEXP_COUNT('[0-9]/[0-9]',PUR_ORD)>0 OR LOCATE('*',PUR_ORD)>0 OR LOCATE('BAM',PUR_ORD)>0
                   THEN 'BAM' ELSE'' END AS BAMYN 
             ,CASE WHEN REGEXP_COUNT('[0-9]/[0-9]',PUR_ORD)>0 
                   THEN CAST(SUBSTRING(PUR_ORD,LOCATE('/',PUR_ORD)-2,5) AS DATE)
                   ELSE ORD_DATE  END AS soldorstockdate 


FROM table a
```

I am getting the following error

SQL Error [2201S]: [SQ20558] Regular expression string for function REGEXP_COUNT not valid.

Thanks,
Arun

Comment: What version of DB2 are you using?

Comment: u forget in second line `, CASE WHEN` u use only 'WHEN'.
and u have to change parameter in regexp_count `REGEXP_COUNT(<string>,<search-regex>)`...

Comment: @pringi: I am using 7.3

Comment: Check the prerequisites on: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.3?topic=functions-regexp-count. Do you have ICU installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.
According to your description the `SOLDORSTOCKDATE` column can't contain empty values, but it has them in your desired result which is strange.

```
SELECT 
  A.*
, CASE 
    WHEN REGEXP_COUNT (ORDERSTATUS, 'S.*LD') <> 0 
      THEN 'Sold' 
    WHEN REGEXP_COUNT (ORDERSTATUS, 'STOCK|STK [0-9]') <> 0 
      THEN 'Stock' 
    ELSE '' 
  END AS comment 
, CASE 
    WHEN REGEXP_COUNT (ORDERSTATUS, '[0-9]/[0-9]|\*|BAM') <> 0
      THEN 'BAM' 
    ELSE '' 
  END AS BAMYN 
, COALESCE (DATE (TO_DATE (REGEXP_SUBSTR (ORDERSTATUS, '[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}') || '/2022', 'MM/DD/YYYY')), orddate)  
      AS soldorstockdate 
FROM ##input A
```

| SEGMENT | MMODEL | BRAND | ORDERSTATUS | ORDDATE | COMMENT | BAMYN | SOLDORSTOCKDATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| maka | M12E4 | Nimg | *SLD 05/11/2022 | 2022-05-01 | Sold | BAM | 2022-05-11 |
| sika | KL6781 | Cheung | 37141 SLD BAM | 2022-05-05 | Sold | BAM | 2022-05-05 |
| kloi | NB1290 | Vloti | 1277489 STK#39298.32831 | 2022-05-04 |  |  | 2022-05-04 |
| Ping | BN1289 | gower | 36888 SLD FLOREN ANGEL | 2022-05-06 | Sold |  | 2022-05-06 |
| Melow | VB1901 | operw | 1286664 051222 | 2022-05-10 |  |  | 2022-05-10 |
| Bekow | XC901 | mewar | *SLD 5/14/22 Heman | 2022-05-03 | Sold | BAM | 2022-05-14 |
| Nakin | JH121 | korew | STOCK | 2022-05-16 | Stock |  | 2022-05-16 |
| Verura | CV123 | thilla | 1287002 LONGMINT | 2022-05-12 |  |  | 2022-05-12 |
| Chaluli | BN8901 | dora | STOCK BAM 5/17/22 | 2022-05-11 | Stock | BAM | 2022-05-17 |
| Kroger | XC123 | iops | *STOCK BAM 5/23/22 | 2022-05-08 | Stock | BAM | 2022-05-23 |
| beqow | VB123 | pirar | 3902120 STOCK | 2022-05-20 | Stock |  | 2022-05-20 |
| Viast | NM41W | kolpe | SOLD BRANDON BOX 36790 | 2022-05-15 | Sold |  | 2022-05-15 |
| Chimmin | BN123 | tyrow | STK 5/13 | 2022-05-03 | Stock | BAM | 2022-05-13 |
| Bellow | Vio23 | Callow | *STK 5/13/22 | 2022-05-05 | Stock | BAM | 2022-05-13 |
| Nalla | Krowmin | Gilqa | 37938 STOCK 5/18/22 PER SARA | 2022-05-18 | Stock | BAM | 2022-05-18 |

Comment: Hi @MARK Barinstein ...Still I am getting this error SQL Error [2201S]: [SQ20558] Regular expression string for function REGEXP_COUNT not valid.

Comment: It must work on Db2 for IBM i. I don't have 7.3 at hand but it works on my 7.5. You either don't run it as is or your Db2 is not Db2 for IBM i or something unusual happens to your system. Show this error to your system administrator.

Comment: SELECT a.*, CASE WHEN REGEXP_COUNT(ORDERSTATUS,'S.*LD')<>0 THEN 'Sold' 
 ELSE'Stock' END AS comment 
         ,CASE WHEN  REGEXP_COUNT (ORDERSTATUS,'*|BAM')<>0 
               THEN 'BAM' ELSE'' END AS BAMYN ,
 COALESCE (DATE (TO_DATE (REGEXP_SUBSTR (ORDERSTATUS , '[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}') || '/2022', 'MM/DD/YYYY')), ORDDATE)  
      AS soldorstockdate
FROM ctable a

Comment: Really wrong pattern. You must escape the special character `*` in the 2-nd pattern, if you want to search for `*` character in the input string. Unescaped `*` in the 1-st one means "zero or more times" of the preceding character (`.` there means any character). Use `REGEXP_COUNT (ORDERSTATUS,'\*|BAM')` instead, .

Comment: Hi @Mark Barinstein..This is awesome..This really works for me!!

Comment: HI @Mark Barinstein...Can I modify this statement CASE 
    WHEN REGEXP_COUNT (ORDERSTATUS, '\*SLD|BAM') <> 0

Comment: Also I need to extract the date within the column orderstatus only when *SLD or BAM is present otherwise i need to have only the orddate as the soldorstockdate

Comment: CASE
 WHEN REGEXP_COUNT (ORDERSTATUS, '\\*|BAM') <> 0 AND REGEXP_COUNT (ORDERSTATUS, '[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}') <> 0 
   THEN DATE (TO_DATE (REGEXP_SUBSTR (ORDERSTATUS, '[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}') || '/2022', 'MM/DD/YYYY'))
   ELSE orddate
  END 
      AS soldorstockdate